# IncompatibleClassChangeError on inflating layout containing map fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm getting crash reports with this stacktrace on Android N:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class rr implements non-interface class rq (declaration of 'rr' appears in /data/app/<package_name>-1/base.apk)
       at tb.b(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.bu.i(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.bu.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.b.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.b.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(SourceFile:1939)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:978)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(SourceFile:2256)
       at android.support.v4.view.aq.onCreateView(SourceFile:44)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
       at <package_name>.dy.onCreateView(SourceFile:31)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(SourceFile:1962)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1016)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1197)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(SourceFile:738)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:1562)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(SourceFile:535)
```

The crashes happen in oncreateview of a map fragment which is shown in a view pager.

This is the line on which the crash happens:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
```

Has anyone experienced something like this? This has only started coming in the last release although I haven't changed anything. I'm using google play services 9.0.0. I haven't seen this ever before.

Is it a bug? How can I solve it?

**Update**

R.layout.map_fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/placeDetailsMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:cameraBearing="0"
        map:cameraTilt="30"
        map:cameraZoom="15"
        map:mapType="normal"
        map:uiCompass="true"
        map:uiRotateGestures="true"
        map:uiScrollGestures="true"
        map:uiTiltGestures="true"
        map:uiZoomControls="true"
        map:uiZoomGestures="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update 2**

More crashes came in, turns out it's only on Android N.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @Gaurav what code in specific do you wanna see? The trace says the issue is in the play services.

Comment: the map fragment in which you are inflating the layout as well as the layout file

Comment: @Gaurav I forgot to reply when I updated the question, sorry!